# Exprimer la confusion

Tags: vocabulaire

Comment traduire en français l'expression anglaise signifiant la confusion du sujet : *to be confused*?

J'aurais tendance à traduire par "je suis perdu" ou "je ne sais plus où j'en suis" mais me demande si "être confus" peut avoir aussi ce sens en français?

Pour moi non, "je suis confus" est une expression de politesse que l'on dit lorsqu'on souhaite présenter ses excuses ; "il est confus" / "tu es confus" signifie que la personne dont on parle s'exprime mal et est difficile à comprendre (on peut aussi dire qu'un livre est confus...). Mais j'ai un doute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour exprimer le fait qu'on ne sait pas trop où on en est, qu'on ne sait quel jugement former, qu'on a un avis mais qu'on doute d'avoir raison, il est possible d'utiliser

```
Je suis perplexe.
```

Cependant, dans certain contexte, **je suis perplexe** peut également signifier que l'on remet (poliment) en question une affirmation ('perplexe' penche alors vers **dubitatif**, qui serait moins ambigu dans ce contexte-là.)

D'un autre côté, comme vous le signalez, **Je suis confus** a pris le sens de: "Je ne sais pas comment m'excuser" (tout comme l'expression "se confondre en excuses"). Toutefois, l'adjectif confus n'a pas nécessairement cette notion de honte: cela dépend aussi de son utilisation dans la phrase. Par exemple, on peut dire :

```
Tout cela est très confus pour moi.
```

pour indiquer que l'on n'y comprend rien, sans en être embarassé pour autant,  ou encore

```
Ses paroles étaient confuses.
```

pour parler de quelqu'un qui ne s'exprime pas clairement.

Enfin, une autre solution pour dire qu'on ne sait **VRAIMENT** plus où on en est, est d'utiliser:

```
Je suis déboussolé.
```

Answer (score 1):

Un peu de clarté... dans la confusion ! ;-) :

Pour exprimer un état de cette sorte de chose, tu as :

- L'adjectif ***confus*** directement emprunté au latin *confusus* participe passé de *confundere* (confondre). Attesté dès le XIIè et d'abord au sens de *couvert de honte*.
  Il a depuis vécu sa vie propre.
- L'adjectif ***confondu*** directement issu du participe passé du verbe français *confondre*. Utilisé au sens très fort de *troublé, déconcerté* à la même époque. Il vivra sa vie propre de son coté lui aussi.

C'est ce dernier sens que rend l'anglais *"to be confused"*.
 *Être confus*, traduisant plutôt l'anglais *"to be embarassed"*

Tu as donc bien raison de conserver à *être confus* le sens de honte et d'excuses donc conséquentes.